# RPG game with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the player to attack the enemy using the on click button and every time the button is click the health point from each the player and the enemy will be decrease. So its like they are attack each other until one of their health point reaches 0. I have the characters set as object.

I have already set up the code and its not working, I think because my code isn't grabbing the health points from both character. Any suggestion will help a lot. Thank you.

```
 $("#attack").on("click", function() { 
    if(isGameover === false) {
        enemySelected.healthPoints -= characterSelected.attackPower;
        characterSelected.healthPoints -= enemySelected.counterAttackPower;
        $('#' + characterSelected.name + "HP").html("HP: " + characterSelected.healthPoints);
        $('#' + enemySelected.name + "HP").html("HP: " + enemySelected.healthPoints);
        console.log(enemySelected.healthPoints);
    }

});
```

Comment: Can you post the whole page's code?

Comment: yeah lets me post them, they are a bit long though.

Comment: Use [tag:reactjs] ... Your code will be cleaner

Comment: JavaScript has a single thread. So you can't really do things in parallel. You should use `Math.random();` to generate damage dealt and damage taken. Each side should be an array of objects. Each object then is paired off with another object from the opposing array. Any extra objects on one side or the other could gain up on another object giving that side the tactical advantage of superior numbers.

Comment: @zer00ne I will keep that in mind. Right now I have each character as an object like this 
     name: "survivor",
 healthPoints: 120,
 baseAttackPower: 8,
 counterAttackPower: 10,
 attackPower: 8
};

var ghoul = {
 name: "ghoul",
 healthPoints: 100,
 baseAttackPower: 10,
 counterAttackPower: 15,
 attackPower: 10
};

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI I wish we can use reactjs. Our class haven't learn it yet and one of the requirement for this assignment is to use jquery and javascript only. Thank you for your suggestion though.